# want to read number of words and charecter using javascript

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching

consider, in my javascript i am getting :

```
function callBack_Show(result) {
//where result is in jsonp format

var artical= result.Artical;
```

now artical contains some text,

i want to read number of words and characters in it and display them
the words can be separated by: blank space, fullstop,comma etc
and i want to do it in same javascript function (callBack_Show(result) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of words, you can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Split) the text using a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions) where you can define what is your criteria for separating words.

To get the number of characters, you can use the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Length) property of the String, eg.:

```
var words = artical.split(/[\s.,]/).length; // whitespace, dot and comma
var characters = artical.length;
```

Comment: i have an addition to this problem
in above example 
result.artical would be HTML text 
for ex.
<div class="StoryArticleInfo"><p><p>BODY&nbsp;Article By Archie(Used By Story Tool)</p>

and i want to read number of actual text words and characters
ie:
BODY Article By Archie(Used By Story Tool)
pls help, 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the number of words you want to use the [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Split) method, and then use the `length` property of the resultant Array. To count the number of characters use the `String.length` property.